# Change button background on mouseOver in WPF/XAML- Style Triggers not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to change the background of my buttons on a mouseOver. In the following code I don't get any errors, it shows the default background color it just doesn't change the background color on mouseover.

Here is my code:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>

    <Style x:Key = "RoundButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="12" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Any idea why it is not changing the background to red when mouseOver?

**EDIT:**
I'm not sure if this is related but I don't get the mouse effect when hovering over, in other words, the mouse arrow doesn't change to a hand when hovering over the buttons.

Comment: does Button have any background when mouse isn't over it?

Comment: Yes it does. What it doesn't have is the mouse effect when hovering over, in other words, the mouse arrow doesn't change to a hand when hovering over.

Comment: By doing it this way you've effectively replaced the whole default `ControlTemplate` so any other existing effects like hover provided by the default would need to be incorporated yourself. I'd recommend taking a look at [the default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates) and customizing from there using `VisualStateManager` or just apply a different resource at the instance for `<Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>` instead.

Comment: Make sense, thank you for your suggestions.